# Spark: Printing elements from Nested DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I am trying to print specific elements from a `DataFrame` which contains nested values:

This is the `Spark SQL DataFrame` I get:

```
scala>result
org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [P1: struct<t1:tinyint,t2:tinyint,t3:smallint,t4:int>, P2:struct<k1:tinyint,k2:int>]
```

It contains :

```
scala>result.take(3).foreach(println)
[[15,78,60,1111111],[10,7525619]]
[[15,78,60,2222222],[10,7525620]]
[[15,78,60,3333333],[10,7525621]]
```

How can I print only the 2nd and the 3rd field from the first struct?

I tried this:

```
scala>result.take(3).foreach(l => printf("Num: %d-%d\n", l(0,2),l(0,3)))
```

and got an error.`error: too many arguments for method apply: (i: Int)Any in trait Row`

Comment: You should add the defintion of the data frame and the error message to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Index-based access

```
result.select("p1._2", "p1._3").show()
```

## Using case classes

You could use a `case class` upfront:

```
case class A(a1: Int, a2: Int, a3: Int, a4: Int)
case class B(b1: Int, b2: Int)
case class Record(a: A, b: B)
```

to avoid the index-based access by giving meaningful names to the nested structures and the values.

Then define the data frame

```
val df = sc.parallelize(
  Seq(
    Record(A(15, 78, 60, 1111111), B(10, 7525619)),
    Record(A(15, 78, 60, 1111111), B(10, 7525619)))).toDF()
```

and now

```
df.select($"a.a2", $"a.a3").show()
```

or

```
df.registerTempTable("df")
sqlContext.sql("select a.a2, a.a3 from df").show()
```

---

As an alternative, using an `RDD`:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(
  Seq(
    Record(A(15, 78, 60, 1111111), B(10, 7525619)),
    Record(A(15, 78, 60, 1111111), B(10, 7525619))))
```

then you can directly `map` over the `case class`:

```
rdd.map {
  rec =>
    (rec.a.a2, rec.a.a3)
}.collect()
```

Comment: @Arik Do you need any more help with this question? If it solved your problem, you could accept this answer.